# Changing background color of the form with hexadecimal code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one method named ***ChangeFormBackground(Color colorName)*** which changes the form background with the ***colorname*** which is the parameter of the method.Now when I call this method I have not color name but the hexadecimal code of the color and I want to change the background color of the form with that hexadecimal code using that method then what should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will always work because it doesn't contain alpha color (which is not supported by BackColor property):

```
Color temp = Color.FromArgb(0xFF00FF);
Color result = Color.FromArgb(temp.R, temp.G, temp.B);
```

Comment: Which alpha does `Color.FromArgb(0xFF00FF);` use?

Answer (score 36):

```
using System.Windows.Media;
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

(this assumes an ARGB value)

or

```
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC66");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx) method:

```
Color.FromArgb(0x78FF0000);
```

Comment: Mind that a Form.BackColor doesn't support alpha / transparancy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ColorConverter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colorconverter.aspx) for manipulating color representations.