# How do I get the forecolor of an control?

Tags: c#, colors, get, label

How do you get the color of a control, such as a label or rectangle? I need to do something like this:

```
if (label.foreground == #FFFFFF)
    Messagebox.Show("Branco!").
```

For awhile, I resolved my case with this:

```
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
if (rec.Fill == mySolidColorBrush)
    MessageBox.Show("Branco!");
```

Here are the errors I'm getting when I try the answers already posted:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know you're using WPF, here's how to set the color on your label. Use the [`Foreground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground.aspx) property and set it to a valid [`Brushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx) value.

```
if (label.Foreground = Brushes.White)
    MessageBox.Show("Branco!");
```

Same with the rectangle:

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Fill = Brushes.Green;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (label.ForeColor == System.Drawing.Color.Black) 
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx) the Type of `ForeColor` is `System.Drawing.Color`, which mean you need to compare your element color with a predefined color in `System.Drawing.SystemColors`

**EDIT**

kindly check these question
[Changing background color of the form with hexadecimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243370/changing-background-color-of-the-form-with-hexadecimal-code)
[convert hex code to color name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791710/convert-hex-code-to-color-name)

try something like this

```
if (label.ForeColor == Color.FromArgb(0xFFFFFF)) Messagebox.Show("Branco!");
```