# Change the color of the button by using html color codes

Tags: c#, html, button, colors, windows-forms-designer

I want to change the color of the `button` when it is pressed in `windows form` app and I want to use the color codes. Is there a way to make `button` color **#C0C0C0** ??

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243439/6170890)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rgb equivalent.Color spaces of `#c0c0c0` **RGB** =   192 192 192

```
     button1.ForeColor= Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This may help you..
<script>
function changeCol(btnid){
    document.getElementById(btnid).style.backgroundColor = "#ff00F0";
}
</script>
<input type = "button" id = "btn" value="$alt1" onClick="changeCol('btn')">
```

Comment: this answer for web design not for windows form design